# Android Popup with EditText, keyboard blocks text, background scrolls

Tags: java, android, popup

I have a Popup which holds a couple of EditTexts in a ScrollView.
When i click on an EditText it scrolls up the View in background, not the Popup, therefore the keyboard blocks the EditText.

Any ideas ?

```
PopupWindow popUp = new PopupWindow(this);
popUp.update(0, 0, display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());
popUp.setFocusable(true);

LinearLayout llh = new LinearLayout(this)
llh.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

EditText e1,e2,e3...
llh.addView(e1);    
llh.addView(e2);    
llh.addView(e3);
...
sv.addView(llh);
popUp.setContentView(llh);
popUp.showAtLocation(llh, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
```

This is "launched" from a View which holds a ScrollView aswell.

If there is a workaround for this, it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same problem as you, and to solve it, i created a custom `Dialog` and with a custom theme (`R.style.ThemeDialogCustom` in the following example). I also set `dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` and `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);` and i set a custom layout with `setContentView`. Something like this:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activityContext, R.style.ThemeDialogCustom);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true); 
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);
```

In other words, the above piece of code tries to immitate the behavior of a `PopupWindow`.

**EDIT** For clarification purposes, if you need to access a view that was defined in the dialog's custom layout, you can access it like this:

```
EditText e1 = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.e1);
```

Hope that helps.